# Why do derivatives behave like fractions when they are not fractions but an operator as a whole?

Tags: derivatives

The operator  $\frac{d}{dx}$ sometimes behaves like a fraction.For eg. when we use chain rule to write $\frac {d}{dy}=\frac {d}{dx}\frac {dx}{dy}$ it apparently seems the $dx$ cancel out to give the previous thing.Also when differentiating parametric functions we use $\frac {dy}{dx}=\frac {dy/dt}{dx/dt}$ it seems that the $dt$ cancel out as if they were fractions.

I referred a few books but could not find any explanations (rather how the thing works).I will be great if someone explains this.

Thanks for any help!!

Comment: They are fractions, but this interpretation has gone out of style. A. Ya. Khinchin's book _Eight Lectures on Mathematical Analysis_ explains this.

Comment: You might want to look at previous questions on this topic, such as https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1784671

Comment: similar questions ([here](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/21199/is-frac-textrmdy-textrmdx-not-a-ratio), [here](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1906241/when-not-to-treat-dy-dx-as-a-fraction-in-single-variable-calculus?rq=1))

Comment: 3blue1brown has a [video](https://youtu.be/YG15m2VwSjA?list=PLZHQObOWTQDMsr9K-rj53DwVRMYO3t5Yr&t=520) that may help with this. The link takes you to the relevant part of the video, but I recommend watching the whole thing if any part of it seems confusing.

Comment: They are fractions. Note that the derivative is defined as the limit of a fraction!

Comment: More precisely, they _were_ fractions, before taking the limit.

Comment: @quasi But when I write dx I have already taken the limit and carrying out my operations on basis of what I obtained after taking the limit...

Comment: @tatan -- Yes, but when you roll back to the before-limit context, the laws of multiplying fractions were applicable. So (informally), roll back, multiply the fractions, take the new limit, and compare against taking the limits first, and multiplying later.

Comment: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Chain_rule#First_proof

Comment: I reread the Khinchin thing last night, it's brilliant.  (Section 32 if you are looking for it.)  I can't do it justice by summarizing, because it's so pithy.  But Khinchin says, let $y$ be a function of $x$, and let $\Delta x$ be a small increment in $x$; this produces a corresponding small increment in $y$ which we can call $\Delta y$.  This $\Delta y$ is in general hard to calculate, but if we define $dy = y'(x) \Delta x$, then $dy$ is fairly easy to calculate.  The notation is a little odd, because $dy$ is actually a function of both $x$ and $\Delta x$. But…

Comment: One can show that $dy$ is a good approximation to $\Delta y$ in the following sense: The quantity $\alpha = \Delta y - dy$ is infinitesimal as $\Delta x\to 0$, and moreover it is an infinitesimal of a higher order than $\Delta y$, so if you replace $\Delta y$ with $dy$, not only does the absolute error introduced go to zero as $\Delta x\to 0$ but also the relative error.

Comment: Moreover, the quantity $dy$ is completely characterized by that property and by the property of being a linear function of $\Delta x$; it is the unique linear approximation to $\Delta y$ that gives an infinitesimal relative error. Khinchin observes that one can use those two characterizing properties as a definition of $dy$ independent of the derivative, and then define the derivative in terms of differentials as $\lim_{\Delta x\to 0}\frac{dy}{dx}$ if one wants; one can also prove the chain rule based on quotients of differentials defined in this way.

Comment: @MJD Thanks for your help!!!